# positionig view in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am searching for 4 days but can't reach any solution.

In my iOS app i am trying to use push notifications and there is no problem there. I receive notification and in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method with using following code i can reach detail view with no problem.

```
NSDictionary *aps = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
NSArray *array = [[aps objectForKey:@"acme"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSArray *fixtureArray = [[CreateFixture alloc] createFixtureWithArray:array andStyle:@"single"];

UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UIViewController *root = navController.topViewController;
FPViewController *vc = [[FPViewController alloc] init];
[vc createViewWithArray:fixtureArray];

NSArray *vcs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:root, vc, nil];
[navController setViewControllers:vcs animated:YES];
```

When i close the app completely and send notification, my app opens with `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` as expected. I am using same code in following `if` statement:

```
if (launchOptions != nil)
{
NSDictionary* dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (dictionary != nil)
    {
        same code above
    }
}
```

BUT!!! this time my detail view comes up with different x y and width height. So the app become useless. some labels and buttons not seen some view bigger and over some other views.
İ can't find any solution PLEASE HELP! (All the views, labels, buttons etc. are created programmatically) i am using autoresizingMask for landscape and portrait window. And i am open for any suggestion. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

i think overriding the `drawRect` method solves this problem.and set frames in drawRect method

Comment: I am creating UIViews in FPViewController.m. I mean i have no any view.m file. where can i use drawRect i don't know. Could you explain with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference i don't know but changing the push detail view code solve the problem.

Here is my old code

```
NSDictionary *aps = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
NSArray *array = [[aps objectForKey:@"acme"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSArray *fixtureArray = [[CreateFixture alloc] createFixtureWithArray:array andStyle:@"single"];

UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UIViewController *root = navController.topViewController; //delete
FPViewController *vc = [[FPViewController alloc] init];
[vc createViewWithArray:fixtureArray];

NSArray *vcs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:root, vc, nil]; //delete
[navController setViewControllers:vcs animated:YES]; //delete
```

And i delete root viewcontroller and setViewControllers: method.

and added pushViewController: animated: method.

```
[navController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

hope some one with same problem don't loose 5 days. Good luck all.